# Неверное задание условия для Linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

Пишу код на винде, запускаю на линуксе. На винде всё отрабатывает так, как я и хочу. При запуске на линуксе - беда (я уже задавал похожий вопрос, что код на винде и линуксе отрабатывал по-разному, тогда решением было перезалить код на линукс ещё раз - в этот раз оно так не работает).
Вот код:

```
public class MainClass : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<MainClass> _logger;

    public MainClass(
        ILogger<MainClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    // К сожалению, я либо пользуюсь библиотекой и принимаю object, а затем
    // десериализовываю его до нужных мне классов, либо работаю без библиотеки.
    // Сама библиотека на линуксе проверена - работает (хотя я, естественно, тестировал
    // не абсолютно всё).
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]object body)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("1"); // В логах есть


        // Финт ниже нужен, чтобы получилась не 1 строка Json, а красивый текст
        // с отступами. Так как далее этот текст будет кинут в письме, это важно.
        var originalBodyText = Convert.ToString(JObject.Parse(body.ToString()));

        WebHookHandler webHookHandler = new WebHookHandler(originalBodyText, _logger);

        // Отправка письма. Тут всё гладко и на винде, и на линуксе

        return Ok();
    }

    private class WebHookHandler
    {
        public WebHookHandler(string originalJsonWebHook, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation(originalJsonWebHook); // В логах есть

            if () // Условие, которое не выполняется в тестах
            {
                // Соответственно не сильно важно, что тут происходит
            }
            // Как я писал выше, originalJsonWebHook я кидаю по почте.
            // И я абсолютно уверен, что строка 
            // "  \"event_type\": \"PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED\",\r\n"
            // там есть. Да и в логах originalJsonWebHook присутствует - 
            // там строка тоже етсь.
            else if (originalJsonWebHook.Contains("\"event_type\": \"PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED\",\r\n"))
            {
                logger.LogInformation("2"); // В логах отсутствует

                // Дальнейшая логика
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogInformation("3"); // В логах есть
            }
        }
    }
```

При этом `logger.LogInformation("2")` на винде отрабатывает. Для тестов я один и тот же запрос кидал себе на линукс и на винду - я попадал в разные ветки условий. Может ли быть такое, что линукс по-другому обрабатывает строки? Или ошибка ещё в чём-то?

**UPD:** Сейчас ещё запускал код - `logger.LogInformation(originalJsonWebHook)` отсутствует в логах... Это при том, что ПОСЛЕ него идёт задание параметров письма, а письмо приходит не пустое.

Comment: На линуксе новая строка это `\n`, а не `\r\n`, может поэтому услови и не выполняется?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Спасибо, затестил - не помогло. Пробовал вовсе убрать проверку на переход на новую строку - тоже ничего не поменялось. Хотя теперь я точно знаю, что для линукса условия всё равно придётся переделать :-)

Comment: а вообще, можно было бы не парсить JSON и обратно конвертировать в строку и потом сравнивать строки, а десериализовать строку в обычные объекты .net и работать с ними и проблем с разным форматом строк не было бы, т.к. я пока не вижу смысла конвертировать все туда-сюда

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Это особенность используемой библиотеки. В одном довольно важном месте вместо понятного класса я получаю ``object`` - работать с ним не особо удобно. Чтобы немного облегчить себе жизнь, для реально используемых хуков я сделал наследников от хуков библиотечных, добавив туда нужные мне поля. Получились разные классы и, что хуже, некоторые одинаковые параметры представляют собой разные типы (один даёт строку, другой массив) - я даже объединить эти классы не могу. После ``logger.LogInformation("2")`` у меня как раз и идёт десериализация до сделанных мною наследников

Comment: По поводу переводов строк: **всегда** используйте в своём коде `Environment.NewLine` - это гарантированно даст правильные символы.

Comment: Попробуйте строку, в которой ищете совпадение, куда-нибудь вывести, в тот же лог например, и посмотрите что в ней. Может пробел где лишний/недостающий или еще какое форматирование.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344002/string-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-contains?rq=1) - мой вопрос можно считать дубликатом.

Тем не менее, отдельная благодарность пользователям @ExplodingKitten, @AlexanderPetrov и  @rdorn за полезные советы.

Решением проблемы оказалось использование `if (originalJsonWebHook.IndexOf($"\"event_type\": \"PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED\",{Environment.NewLine}")!=-1)` вместо `Contains`.
Для меня загадкой остаётся то, почему `Contains` по-разному отработал на винде и линуксе.